# *.m file requires external *.mat file for input. Not sure how to implement

Tags: matlab, function

Long time reader first time poster!

I am having the pleasure of learning more advanced MatLab by going through my Professors code, which is proving to be a little difficult.

At the moment we have a GUI which runs some functions on external data and produces some graphs as an output. I would however like to run the function by itself without having to use the GUI.

The function heading looks like this...

```
function info = fn_2d(exp_data, data, options)
```

Where exp_data is a structure *.m file, data is a function stored in the m file itself and options is, well, I'm not sure, but the inputs come from the GUI (such as coordinates of mouse clicks etc).

I'm a little out of my depth but I am going through the code line by line.

Could anyone help me with how to read the exp_data directly from the directory. I tried to add this and excluded exp_data from the input arguments for the function, but it didn't work.

```
exp_data_file = ('Example.mat');
exp_data = matfile(exp_data_file);
```

Again, apologies for being quite so out of my depth.

R

Comment: Maybe try `exp_data_file = load('Example.mat');`. Then `exp_data_file` will be  a structure containing all the variables from `Example.mat` which you can access using dot notation. Eg `A = exp_data_file.VariableA`.

Comment: Benoit_11 - you nailed it. In my mind I was thinking that it would need to go into the file and pull the data I needed out. I didn't realise that I could load the whole thing into the workspace memory. From a first look this is working. Thank you :-)

Comment: excellent then! Good luck and have fun!